# Write a function that takes a number as its argument and construct a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I start learning LISP, and I have a question need your help.

> Write a function NEW-LIST that takes a number as its argument and constructs a list of that length containing all T.

This is my try, but it doesn't work. Could you help me to figure out?

```
(defun same-length (x) 
  (make-list x:initial-element 't))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a space between the `x` and `:initial-element`. Also, the `t` doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: @jkiiski: thank very much for your answer. If I want to creat a list with all element TS instead of T, this code doesn't work anymore. Do you know why?

Comment: `T` is a constant (meaning true), so it doesn't need to be quoted. Other symbols do need to be quoted. If it's a variable name, and you want the value of the variable rather than the name then it shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
* (defun make-t (size)
 (make-list size :initial-element T))

MAKE-T
* (make-t 10)

(T T T T T T T T T T)
*
```

`:initial-element` is a keyword parameter, refer to [functions of common lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html) for more info. And please refer to [doc of `make-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_lis.htm) for more info and examples.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer